# Is it possible to have different calculations based on column value while retaining the column?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have the following table:

```
CREATE TABLE Test(
ID int,
Category NVARCHAR(MAX),
Value1 float,
Value2 float
)
GO

INSERT INTO Test
VALUES(1,'Category 1',1,4)
,(1,'Category 1',2,3)
,(1,'Category 2',3,5)
,(1,'Category 3',4,2)
,(2,'Category 2',5,1)
,(2,'Category 2',6,3)
,(2,'Category 2',7,6)
,(2,'Category 3',8,3)
,(2,'Category 1',1,2)
,(3,'Category 1',2,4)
,(3,'Category 1',3,5)
,(3,'Category 1',4,7)
,(3,'Category 2',5,8)
,(3,'Category 3',6,9)
```

I would like to sum Value1 and Value2 by ID and Category and have a different calculation based on the value of the category, while retaining the category value.

For reference the desired result is as follows:

[image: Expected result]

I have tried the following:

```
SELECT
  ID,
  Category,
  CASE
    WHEN Category = 'Category 1' THEN (SUM(CASE WHEN Category = 'Category 1' THEN Value1 ELSE 0 END) + SUM(CASE WHEN Category = 'Category 2' THEN Value1 ELSE 0 END)) - SUM(CASE WHEN Category = 'Category 3' THEN Value1 ELSE 0 END)
    WHEN Category = 'Category 2' THEN (SUM(CASE WHEN Category = 'Category 1' THEN Value1 ELSE 0 END) - SUM(CASE WHEN Category = 'Category 2' THEN Value1 ELSE 0 END)) * SUM(CASE WHEN Category = 'Category 3' THEN Value1 ELSE 0 END)
    WHEN Category = 'Category 3' THEN SUM(CASE WHEN Category = 'Category 3' THEN Value1 ELSE 0 END)
    ELSE 0
  END AS Value1,
    CASE
    WHEN Category = 'Category 1' THEN (SUM(CASE WHEN Category = 'Category 1' THEN Value2 ELSE 0 END) + SUM(CASE WHEN Category = 'Category 2' THEN Value2 ELSE 0 END)) - SUM(CASE WHEN Category = 'Category 3' THEN Value2 ELSE 0 END)
    WHEN Category = 'Category 2' THEN (SUM(CASE WHEN Category = 'Category 1' THEN Value2 ELSE 0 END) - SUM(CASE WHEN Category = 'Category 2' THEN Value2 ELSE 0 END)) * SUM(CASE WHEN Category = 'Category 3' THEN Value2 ELSE 0 END)
    WHEN Category = 'Category 3' THEN SUM(CASE WHEN Category = 'Category 3' THEN Value2 ELSE 0 END)
    ELSE 0
  END AS Value2
FROM dbo.Test
GROUP BY ID, Category
ORDER BY ID, Category
```

But I believe the calculation does not work because of the GROUP BY Category which means that it can't find e.g. Category 2 values when the case when is Category 1. Currently the code works using a UNION ALL and selecting the table each time a new calculation is needed, but the hope is that there will be a faster way to do this as the main table is 500k+ rows long and currently the query takes a long time to run as there are many other calculations to perform. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Place the case expression INSIDE the aggregate function. The case expression evaluates to a value,  then the aggregation occurs. Its called "conditional aggregation"

Comment: A `case expression` simply evaluates to a SINGLE value (per row) hence you cannot SUM multiple rows inside a case expression - unless you run a "correlated subquery".

Answer (score 1):

when you use correlated subqueries, you can get ypur result.

```
SELECT
  ID,
  Category,
  CASE
    WHEN Category = 'Category 1' THEN (SELECT (SUM(CASE WHEN Category = 'Category 1' THEN Value1 ELSE 0 END) + SUM(CASE WHEN Category = 'Category 2' THEN Value1 ELSE 0 END)) 
  - SUM(CASE WHEN Category = 'Category 3' THEN Value1 ELSE 0 END) FROM Test WHERE id = t1.id)
    WHEN Category = 'Category 2' THEN (SELECT (SUM(CASE WHEN Category = 'Category 1' THEN Value1 ELSE 0 END) - SUM(CASE WHEN Category = 'Category 2' THEN Value1 ELSE 0 END)) * SUM(CASE WHEN Category = 'Category 3' THEN Value1 ELSE 0 END) FROM Test WHERE id = t1.id)
    WHEN Category = 'Category 3' THEN (SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN Category = 'Category 3' THEN Value1 ELSE 0 END) FROM Test WHERE id = t1.id)
    ELSE 0
  END AS Value1,
    CASE
    WHEN Category = 'Category 1' THEN (SELECT (SUM(CASE WHEN Category = 'Category 1' THEN Value2 ELSE 0 END) + SUM(CASE WHEN Category = 'Category 2' THEN Value2 ELSE 0 END)) - SUM(CASE WHEN Category = 'Category 3' THEN Value2 ELSE 0 END)  FROM Test WHERE id = t1.id)
    WHEN Category = 'Category 2' THEN (SELECT (SUM(CASE WHEN Category = 'Category 1' THEN Value2 ELSE 0 END) - SUM(CASE WHEN Category = 'Category 2' THEN Value2 ELSE 0 END)) * SUM(CASE WHEN Category = 'Category 3' THEN Value2 ELSE 0 END)  FROM Test WHERE id = t1.id)
    WHEN Category = 'Category 3' THEN (SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN Category = 'Category 3' THEN Value2 ELSE 0 END)  FROM Test WHERE id = t1.id)
    ELSE 0
  END AS Value2
FROM Test t1
GROUP BY ID, Category
ORDER BY ID, Category
```

| ID | Category | Value1 | Value2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Category 1 | 2 | 10 |
| 1 | Category 2 | 0 | 4 |
| 1 | Category 3 | 4 | 2 |
| 2 | Category 1 | 11 | 9 |
| 2 | Category 2 | -136 | -24 |
| 2 | Category 3 | 8 | 3 |
| 3 | Category 1 | 8 | 15 |
| 3 | Category 2 | 24 | 72 |
| 3 | Category 3 | 6 | 9 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/Em02ohZj)